# Twitter Fabric login with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, twitter, twitter-fabric, twitter-login

I am trying to achieve Twitter Fabric login with Firebase , 
Here is my code....
i added manifest entry , and require fabric dependencies..

Declaration of Twitter key and Secret Key which are Taken from Fabric

```
  private static final String TWITTER_KEY = "*********************";
        private static final String TWITTER_SECRET = "****************************************";
```

Here is my Code on MainActivity 's `onCreate()

```
 final TwitterAuthConfig authConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TWITTER_KEY, TWITTER_SECRET);
            Fabric.with(this, new Twitter(authConfig));

    logintwitterButton = (TwitterLoginButton) findViewById(R.id.twitter_login_button);
            logintwitterButton.setCallback(new com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback<TwitterSession>() {
                @Override
                public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result) {
                    TwitterSession session = result.data;
                    // TODO: Remove toast and use the TwitterSession's userID
                    // with your app's user model
                    String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
                    Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);

                }
            });
```

and onActivityResult()

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       logintwitterButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    }
```

and i also set CallBackurl in Twitter Application which get from Firebase...
but Firebase is Completely different thing which is not related to this error..

```
    D/TwitterKit: Login with Twitter failure
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
                                                                            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
                                                                            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:194)
                                                                            at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.Callback.onResponse(Callback.java:42)
                                                                            at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

`
```

is it something i am missing in this...

Comment: If you check the [Firebase Authentication documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/) you won't find Fabric as a supported identity provider. That means that you will have to implement your own provider (on an app server, not in the Android code) to [mint a Firebase Authentication token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) from the Fabric one and [use that custom token to sign in with Firebase from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth).

Comment: though it is not mention in it but it work with Fabric, too. i just try with different fabric account and it works fine for me still don't know what is the problem in it exactly.